# WPF application fails to show OpenFileWith dialog on windows 11

Tags: wpf, windows-11

I have an application that has to present the user with the windows openwith dialog. I have been using the following code:

```
var args = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "shell32.dll");
        args += ",OpenAs_RunDLL " + path;
        Process.Start("rundll32.exe", args);
```

On Windows 11 I experience:

- It works when the user clicks a button
- It works when an external event triggers to open a file when the debugger is attached
- It does not work when an external event triggers to open a file when the debugger is not attached.
  External event = the application can receive a message from a NamedPipe listener.

I also tried SHOpenWithDialog.

The same code (Runas) was working well under previous version of Windows.
It has to be able to run under normal user priviliges (no admin).